# Excel 2013 find function for numbers

Tags: excel, find, formula

I am trying to understand why this formula gives syntax error in Excel 2013:

```
=FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};A1&"0123456789")
```

Worked well when looking for one number only:

```
=FIND({0};A1&"0123456789")
```

But having issue when trying to look for multiple value:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Comment: Do you just want to find the first character that is a number in the string? Is that all you want to get?

Comment: What was your purpose to use this formula?

Answer (score 1):

To get the **position** of the first digit in a string, use:

```
=MIN(FIND({"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},A1&"0123456789"))
```

(*which will return a* ***3*** *in the example below*). To get the **value** of the first digit in a string use:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},A1&"0123456789")),1)
```

[image]

*(your version of Excel may require* **;** *rather than* **,**)

**EDIT#1:**

If you wish to **parse** a string and extract all the digits, use the *array formula*:

```
=--MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A1,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A1,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: it worked like this : =MIN(FIND({"0";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9"};A1&"0123456789"))

Comment: Ultimatly I am trying to seperare numbers and letters from a given string.

Comment: @DidierLaplante  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Perfect - thank you for solution - I am not stuck anymore.